# Code coverage report is not generating

Tags: phpunit, php-code-coverage

When run command `phpunit --bootstrap="TestHelper.php"  --coverage-clover coverage.xml --whitelist="../../../" --debug --log-junit result.xml ./`

It generates result.xml but console get stuck after this line.
**Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ...**

Note : I already checked previous quetion on stackoverflow.

My phpunit.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="./TestHelper.php"
         backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         verbose="true"
         colors="false"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="true">
    <testsuite name="Phalcon - Testsuite">
        <directory>./</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="false">
            <directory suffix=".php">../app/repositories/Account</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../app/repositories/Call</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../app/repositories/Credit</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../app/repositories/User</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="./coverage.xml"/>
        <log type="junit" target="./results.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>

</phpunit>
```

Comment: what's in your phpunit.xml?

Comment: Kasia Gogolek Its working now. Thanks for comment